# Install third party packages via setuptools

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

Is it possible to install say **ffmpeg**, **fftw**, or other **third-party packages** not contained in pip using **setuptools**?

Say that I have the below setup.py (used to distribute a python package via pip)
How can I install ffmpeg and fftw from source or from available distributions (say via **brew install on Mac OS**, or via **apt-get install on Linux**)?

```
import os
import sys
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import Command

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
REQUIRED = [
    "numpy",
    "scipy",
    "matplotlib",
    "xarray",
    "netcdf4",
    "h5py",
    "psutil",
    "sphinx_rtd_theme",
    "tqdm",
    "Sphinx",
    "pyFFTW",
    "ffmpeg",
    "pytest",
]
EXTRAS = {
    'docs': ['Sphinx==3.2.1', 'sphinx_rtd_theme'],
}
CWD = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# SETUP
setup(
    name="...",
    version="...",
    description="...",
    long_description="...",
    author="...",
    author_email="...",
    classifiers=[
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
    ],
    keywords="...",
    url="...",
    license='MIT',
    packages=["..."],
    install_requires="...",
    extras_require="...",
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. `setup.py` is for Python stuff only. If you need to include non-Python libraries, build a deb/rpm for Linux or a pkg installer for MacOS.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought!